# Remix.run useLoaderData returns type any

Tags: loader, remix.run

I was just trying this new thing remix.run and came across this. Everywhere in cos for this  framework they are using const data = useLoaderData() to have type of data variable inferred. But for me this is not working:

```
import { json } from "@remix-run/node";
import type { LoaderFunction, LoaderArgs } from "@remix-run/node";
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";
import { getUsers } from "~/models/users.server";

export const loader: LoaderFunction = async (args: LoaderArgs) => {
  const users = await getUsers();
  return json({ users: users });
};

export default function Users() {
  const { users } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  return (
    <div>
      {users.map((u) => (
        <p key={u.id}>{u.username}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

My VSCode says that variable users has any type and there is a squiggly line red line bellow u in map...what is wrong?
package.json:

```
  "@remix-run/css-bundle": "^1.16.0",
    "@remix-run/node": "^1.16.0",
    "@remix-run/react": "^1.16.0",
    "@remix-run/serve": "^1.16.0",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export async function loader(args: LoaderArgs){
  const users = await getUsers();
  return json({ users: users });
};
```

Try this